# Create a beautiful horizontal line with CSS only

Tags: css

There is a tutorial [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/how-would-i-recreate-this-horizontal-line-in-photoshop) on how to do this in photoshop:

[image]

I am trying to do this with CSS only. The closer I could get is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sydney_o9/yLbtC/4/).

```css
hr.fancy-line { 
    border: 0; 
    height: 1px; 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(215,215,215,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(215,215,215,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(215,215,215,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(215,215,215,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 4px rgba(136,136,136,0.75);
}
```

```html
<hr class="fancy-line"></hr>
```

Doing a gradient on the shadow seems pretty tough.
Any ideas how I could improve this?

Comment: Closest I can get: http://jsfiddle.net/yLbtC/6/

Comment: That's awesome @Passerby. It looks amazing. There a little problem if the div is empty though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/HdwKA/ and http://jsfiddle.net/4yZNN/ 
related results

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I would use a `radial-gradient` to a pseudo-element instead of a `box-shadow` since it tapers off towards the edges nicer.

Position the `radial-gradient` above the `<hr>` so that it's cut in half. Then position another psuedo-element just below the `<hr>`with a the same color as the background and height just large enough to cover the rest of the gradient.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLbtC/5/)

---

**CSS**

```
hr.fancy-line { 
    border: 0; 
    height: 1px;

}
hr.fancy-line:before {
    top: -0.5em;
    height: 1em;
}
hr.fancy-line:after {
    content:'';
    height: 0.5em;
    top: 1px;
}

hr.fancy-line:before, hr.fancy-line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

hr.fancy-line, hr.fancy-line:before {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%);
}

body, hr.fancy-line:after {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a particular reason why you use `em` instead of `px`? Is this a better practice?

Comment: @Patt I try to use `em` more because it scales better if the `font-size` changes. overall the `<hr>` has a height of 1em, which is equal to the current `font-size`. I'd imagine having the `<hr>` take up the amount of space of 1 line sounds fair.

Comment: Maaaaaaate! you are a living legend. This is legitimately the best line I've ever seen in my life. In an equivalence class with ca$h to speak from a mathematical/project mgmt perspective. I accidentally closed this window and then realised I forgot to leave a comment and upvote. IT EVEN FAILS GRACEFULLY TO IE. IEEEEE FOR CHRISTS SAKE!!!!

Comment: To not over-write your page background, change the end CSS from a colour to initial - result: body, hr.fancy-line:after {
    background: initial;
}

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at https://codepen.io/ibrahimjabbari/pen/ozinB.
This website provide 18 styles of horizontal lines. Some seem awesome.

Following is an example.

```
hr.style17 {
    border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
    text-align: center;
}
hr.style17:after {
    content: '§';
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -14px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    color: #8c8b8b;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest form to achieve this:

```
hr{ 
   border: 0; 
   height: 1px; 
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0); 
}
```