# make a down-way radial shadow from an hr

Tags: css

I need a shadow similiar to the one made beautifully here:
[Create a beautiful horizontal line with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215556/create-a-beautiful-horizontal-line-with-css-only)
but to have it facing downwards. try playing with it for a while, didn't make it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mask-box-image` to apply a gradient over another to make it "radial", but it is [non supported](http://caniuse.com/css-masks) except for WebKit-based browsers.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q8L8K/)'s the implementation.