# HTML+CSS. How do I place a horizontal line atop a button?

Tags: css, html

I am an iOS and 3D dev taking on some Web dev work. In HTML/CSS/JS I have found it impossible to do something that I assumed was trivial: place a horizontal line atop a button.

Here is my button with a background image:

```
<button id="myButton" style="background-image: url(assets/cursor-filter-thumbnail.png);" class="igv-filter-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDataTarget">
</button>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.igv-filter-button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 128px;
    border:none;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
}
```

Now I want to place a horizontal line atop this button that I will programmatically move up/down using JS. Can someone place enlighten me?

Comment: I would see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215556/create-a-beautiful-horizontal-line-with-css-only and use :before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) put a container around your button as shown here

```
<span class='linestyle'>
<button id="myButton" style="background-image: url(assets/cursor-filter-  
thumbnail.png);" class="igv-filter-button" data-toggle="modal"   
data-target="#myDataTarget">
</button>
<span>
```

2) Add a css style border-top to your span container

```
 .linestyle { border-top:1px solid black;}
```

3) add padding top to your button.

```
.igv-filter-button    { padding-top:1px;}
```

4) programmatically  adjust the padding for the button.

Comment: xd6_ in the comment has a better answer. the :before will work better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use box-shadow to create the effect you want, and even animate it, but the parent element background color must be solid.

**CSS:**

```
button{
    border:none;
    box-shadow:0 -5px 0 white, 0 -6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo using CSS `transition` and jQuery to animate the line position.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/rKZ3V/2/)