# Create a hr radial-gradient below the line

Tags: html, css

There is a wonderful hr gradient here in the answer (the jsfiddle he links to shows an updated css) - [Create a beautiful horizontal line with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215556/create-a-beautiful-horizontal-line-with-css-only). It is exactly what I am after but I would like the gradient to appear below then line instead of above it.

The html is very simple -

```css
hr.fancy-line {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  /* Keep other elements away from pseudo elements*/
}
hr.fancy-line:before {
  top: -0.5em;
  height: 1em;
}
hr.fancy-line:after {
  content: '';
  height: 0.5em;
  /* half the height of :before */
  top: 1px;
  /* height of hr*/
}
hr.fancy-line:before,
hr.fancy-line:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
hr.fancy-line,
hr.fancy-line:before {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 75%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
}
body,
hr.fancy-line:after {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<hr class="fancy-line"></hr>
```

I have tried various different things but cannot get it to work, plus whenever I change it, the line itself disappears.

Please can someone help... thank you

Comment: Just... move the "cover-up" element...

Comment: I'm very sorry but need a bit more info...what/how do you mean exactly please?

Comment: On `hr.fancy-line:after`, replace `top:1px` with `bottom:1px`. Done.

Comment: Superstar!! thank you, spot on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hr.fancy-line:after {
    content:'';
    height: 0.5em;   
    top: -8px;  /*change or bottom:0; */
}
```

```css
hr.fancy-line {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}
hr.fancy-line:before {
  top: -0.5em;
  height: 1em;
}
hr.fancy-line:after {
  content: '';
  height: 0.5em;
  top: -8px; /*or bottom:0; */
}
hr.fancy-line:before,
hr.fancy-line:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
hr.fancy-line,
hr.fancy-line:before {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 75%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
}
body,
hr.fancy-line:after {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<hr class="fancy-line"></hr>
```