# How to create vertical line using the css code in the given link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the link to another question on stackoverflow.

[Css code to create horizontal line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215556/create-a-beautiful-horizontal-line-with-css-only?newreg=987dd8de95b9456386336c341c8f7a0f)

I love the line created. 
Here is the code I am using for horizontal lines on my site:

```css
hr.fancy-line { 
    border: 0; 
    height: 5px;

}
hr.fancy-line:before {
    top: -0.5em;
    height: 1em;
}
hr.fancy-line:after {
    content:'';
    height: 0.5em;
    top: 1px;
}

hr.fancy-line:before, hr.fancy-line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

hr.fancy-line, hr.fancy-line:before {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%);
}

body, hr.fancy-line:after {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
-Some Text-
<hr class="fancy-line"></hr>
```

Now I want to know: how to modify this code so I would be able to create vertical lines. Here is the link where I have used the above code to create horizontal lines: [Horizontal lines used](http://www.curtain-and-divider.com/)

Comment: Have you tried `height: 234px; width: 2px` in `hr.fancy-line, hr.fancy-line:before`?

Comment: Didn't try that before, but it seems to work. Actually this is nearly what I am looking for as I want these vertical lines to separate column sections. but, I want to add the css in my theme and call it in html of different pages...so i can't be hardcoding width and height in the css code...i hope you understand Cayce..any way i can pass these height and width values when I insert following code in my page html??: <hr class="fancy-line"></hr>

Comment: I don't think you understand hard coding 100%. Hard coding is in line coding. CSS coding is what you want to do. @showdev does basically what I said if not better. If you insert any `hr` with class `fancy-line` then it will take on the styles as you have them in your css.

Comment: Yeah, actually I shouldn't have written hard-coded, I meant something else. Sorry. Yes, it works. Thanks Cayce and showdev.

Comment: Avoid Hardcoding? How about `height: 100vh`? And absolute positioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I styled the element with a narrow width and a tall height.

However, making a vertical line out of an `<hr>` seems non-semantic, so you might want to use a `<span>` or some other element.

```css
body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
hr.fancy-line {
  border: 0;
  height: 180px;
  width: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
}
```

```html
<hr class="fancy-line"></hr>
```

---

The way you implement the lines depends on the context in which you're using them. For example, if lines will be separating elements on the page, you might want to create them as pseudo-elements, like below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
ul li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .5em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 4px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually this is nearly what I am looking for as I want these vertical lines to separate column sections. but, I want to add the css in my theme and call it in html of different pages...so i can't be hardcoding width and height in the css code...i hope i am sounding understandable..any way i can pass these height and width values when I insert following code in my page html??: <hr class="fancy-line"></hr>

Comment: In thumbnail grids, I sometimes use pseudo-elements to create lines that separate `<li>` elements. I've edited an example of that into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see a horizontal line is that that's how visaul web browsers treats `<hr>` (horizontal ruler) elements. That's how the HTML specification define this element.

There is no `<vr>` element or equivalent in HTML, so you'd have to workout something entirely different for that.

Comment: That is not an answer. Just a comment.

Comment: @SalmanA - I agree with you it's a bit borderline, but I still think there's no "better answer" to the question asked. As a "supporting evidence", see the close flags. A full solution is too broad and renders the entire content of the question irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a left or right border for a `div` that surrounds everything within your `body` (or have the `height` of the element set to `100%`).

Comment: that would need a lot of work as my page already using a lot of divs and the content body is divided...i needed something scalable..

Comment: You can give the entire body a left or right border (unless you want things on both sides of the line)

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the `hr` 90 degrees like this:

```
hr.fancy-line {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```css
hr.fancy-line { 
    border: 0; 
    height: 5px;

}
hr.fancy-line:before {
    top: -0.5em;
    height: 1em;
}
hr.fancy-line:after {
    content:'';
    height: 0.5em;
    top: 1px;
}

hr.fancy-line:before, hr.fancy-line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

hr.fancy-line, hr.fancy-line:before {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%);
}

hr.fancy-line {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

body, hr.fancy-line:after {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
-Some Text-
<hr class="fancy-line"></hr>
```

Comment: decent attempt, but I don't think that is what they want it to look like :(

Comment: smart...but it doesn't work like the way i wanted.cayce and showdev reply is working for me...

Answer (score 0):

You have three options if you want to make a hr vertical.

If you need to support old browsers:

```
 hr {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

If you only need to support new browsers use:

```
hr {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
```

Set a small width and large height:

```
hr {
   width: 5px;
   height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I would like the site to look okay on all browsers...rotating the <hr> works but not in the way i want...@cayce k and @showdev replies seem to work like the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @showdev and @Cayce K.

I have now what I was looking for.

Let me put the code here for anyone who wants to do something similar in the future.

```css
body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
hr.fancy-line {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
}
```

```html
<hr class="fancy-line" style="height: 100px; width: 5px;"></hr>
```

I have moved height and width to the html line, so I would insert vertical lines of different height and width on different pages.

Thanks to all others who contributed. This was literally my first question up on stackoverflow. Delighted by the response. Cheers