# Horizontal line but with the shadow at the bottom

Tags: css, line, shadow

I want to create a horizontal line similar to the one found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215556/create-a-beautiful-horizontal-line-with-css-only) and marked as the solution but only with the shadow appearing at the bottom.
The closest I can get is getting the shadow shown in the middle of the line, both up and down.

Comment: Present the code that you've tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.fancy-line { 
    border: 0; 
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}
.fancy-line:before {
    top: -0.5em;
    height: 1em;
}
.fancy-line:after {
    height: 0.5em;
    top: calc(-0.5em + 1px);        /* adjusted this */
}

.fancy-line:before, .fancy-line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.fancy-line, .fancy-line:before {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%);
}

body, .fancy-line:after {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
-Some Text-
<div class="fancy-line"></div>
```

The original code generates a radial gradient and covers the bottom half of it with a block colored the same as the background. Adjusting it to your requirements is just a matter of moving the covering piece from the bottom to the top.

Also, note: `hr` elements are required to be self closing. This precludes the use of `:before` and `:after` since self-closing elements can't have children. In the referenced answer, they weren't using any particular feature of `hr`, so I've converted it to a `div` here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/9rovqvoj/1/

It's basically the same, but adding a mask before pseudo element :before instead of :after and added a z-index to it.

```
hr.fancy-line:after {
  top: -0.5em;
  height: 1em;
}

hr.fancy-line:before {
  content: '';
  height: 0.5em;
  top: -0.5em;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, I will prefer accepting @Ouroborus' answer as the solution because it uses proper HTML code (and it does not use z-index, which is more like a CSS trick for me, as the shadow is generated by the :before pseudo-element).

Comment: it was the z-index in the :before pseudo-element that I was missing to remove the shadow shown on top of the line